# Swift CoreData saving and fetching from a relationship

Tags: swift, core-data

I have coredata in my swift app. I am able to get the two textfields.text to save to core data and the fetch it, but those 2 properties are part of 1 entity. I also have a few other entities with relationships all set up.

When I save to core data what happens is the 2 strings come through, but the relationship strings are nil and the app crashes.

Here is some of my set up

[image: Screenshot of core data]

// MARK: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

```
extension SavedPalauttesViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

  func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {


    tableView.beginUpdates()
  }

  func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {


    tableView.endUpdates()
  }



  func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {


    switch(type) {

    case .insert:
      if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
      }
      break

    case .delete:
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
      }
      break

    case.update:
      if let indexPath = indexPath{
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! LocalPalautteTableViewCell
        configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
      }
      break

    case .move:
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
      }
      if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
      }
      break

    }
  }

  func attemptFetch() {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Palautte> = Palautte.fetchRequest()

    let nameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [nameSort]

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    controller.delegate = self

    self.controller = controller

    do {

      try controller.performFetch()

    } catch {

      let error = error as NSError
      print("\(error)")

    }




  }

}
```

Now the category of type string and name of type string work fine

but when I try to save any of the background colors or foreground...I get nil and a crash

this is part of how I am attempting to save to core data

```
palauttePalautte.category = finalPalautteCategoryValue ?? ""


palauttePalautte.toBackgroundColor?.redValue = String(Int(redBackgroundColorValue))
```

but on the 2nd vc when I try to get a value for it I crash

```
let backRed = palautte.toBackgroundColor?.redValue ?? ""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error message(s) do you see in Xcode when the app crashes?

Comment: You need to *create* a `BackgrondColor` object, set its `redValue` attribute, and then assign it to the `toBackgroundColor` relationship on the `Palautte` object.